# Problemas com layout no Zend

Tags: php, zend, layout

Tenho uma view que é formada por um layout diferente do padrão em meu projeto, seto ele desta forma:

```php
public function init() {
    //Colocando o layout default
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout_paginas');
}
```

Porém o conteúdo deste layout, simplesmente é ignorado, somente é carregado o conteúdo da view, alguém sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo?

**Estou editando aqui pelo seguinte: Todas as actions deste controller funcionam normalmente, somente uma específica não carrega o conteúdo do layout.**

Comment: Você então poderia postar essas actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```php
// Usar o layout layout_paginas.phtml como padrão
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('layout_paginas');
```

Caso contrário, utilize da mesma maneira que você fez, porém informando o caminho relativo do layout:

```php
// Neste caso, o diretório padrão é esse: application/layouts/scripts/
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('application/layouts/scripts/layout_paginas.phtml');
```

Comment: Eu não posso usa-lo como default, pois também já utilizo o default default...por assim dizer...

Comment: @KennyRafael de qualquer forma, tenho certeza que funciona. Basta inserir esse código na sua action em específico (a que não está funcionando). OU no `init()` apenas de teste.

Comment: Obricado, para este caso foi resolvido desta forma...

Comment: @KennyRafael Qual dos métodos resultou para resolver a questão? Definir o layout através do `getMvcInstance()` ou aplicando o caminho no método `setLayout()` _(para futura referência)_?

Comment: Aplicando o caminho no setLayout()

Answer (score 3):

Pelo conteúdo da tua pergunta não sei se está a ter em conta o caminho para o layout:

```php
 $layout->setLayoutPath('caminho/para/o/layout');
```

Mas também podes alterar o teu código para:

```php
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('/caminho/para/o/layout/layout_paginas');
```

**Notas:**
O caminho para o ficheiro é relativo à pasta de layouts, que por defeito está localizada em `application/layouts/scripts/`.

---

#### Se estás a utilizar:

```php
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout_paginas');
```

Efectivamente, estás a dizer para procurar o layout em:

```php
application/layouts/scripts/layout_paginas.phtml
```

---

#### Ajudas:

- [Zend_Layout Início Rápido](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html)

Comment: Sim, ele está em application/layouts/scripts/layout_paginas.phtml